# Automatically start EC2 instance when DNS is requested

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have some EC2 instances running a web application within a Docker and I set them to be stopped automatically while it's outside working time(e.g 7am to 7pm) for cutting costs.  I'd like to know if I can automate the instance to start when the URL of the web app is requested (even when EC2 is stopped), in case someone wants to access outside business hours previously configured.

Some people recommended me to run the application within AWS Lambda, but how do I trigger the function to start with a DNS call?

Comment: You can't do it with Route53. If you have your own custom DNS then maybe you can write a hook, but this is not a good idea.  The idea of DNS is that it responds very quickly, and lookups can be cached, not necessarily handled by your resolver, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is not easily possible. You might find some complex way with lambda and route 53 logging, but even if you do it can take 5 minutes to start an EC2 instance. That means by the time the EC2 instance is started the request has timed out.

**Lambda**

Rewriting your application on lambda / serverless compute would remove this problem. You only pay per request, and you don't pay much in most cases. Most serverless applications cost very little. Some, however, can cost a lot more than EC2 instances.

**Practical Option**

The most practical way to keep costs down is probably to use autoscaling and small compute units and scale out, rather than fewer large instances. You keep one small set of resources running 24/7, with more resources running during your busy periods.

With containers you could consider using Fargate to keep a low resource container running 24/7 then ramp up more resources when load builds. This could be either autoscaling or scheduled scaling. I don't know if you can use Fargate and EC2 within the same ECS cluster but if you can that might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to start an ec2 instance when the URL of the web app is requested. The http request will have timed-out before the instance is ready to serve the request.

There would be no authentication involved meaning that any random request from a bot would trigger the launch of the ec2 instance.

In theory it should be possible to create a stack to do that by for example using an ALB routing requests to a specific path to a Lambda function which could start an ec2 instance. But the resources involved that would be more expensive than letting the instance run 24/7.

If you want to cut costs AWS might not be the best provider for you.